# What is the data structure typically used to map input to the display?

Tags: c++, user-interface, data-structures, input

My problem is how to, given an input, map this input to an area of the display. You can also see this as mapping an input to a widget of a GUI, but my intentions are simply about the generic case.

I'm assuming that when an input is triggered by the hardware sensor/OS I get a pair of [x,y] coordinates.

I was convinced that an array used as a lookup table would be enough for this, you create a 2x2 matrix where each element points to the widget that is that given pixel.

But with this approach there is a problem, an array is a data structure that is "rusty" and doesn't scale at all, I'm not really buying the fact that someone will do this kind of mapping using a simple array, for example with a simple rescale of the window you will have to re-create that array and this is expensive, in terms of computation and memory allocation, without considering the fact that you have to keep both the hierarchy and the layout for the widgets internally, so there is a need for a much more flexible data structure, probably with random access capabilities and really low complexity, around O(1) or O(log(N)).

I can't think about a good data structure that I know that will cope well with this scenario, so what is usually used for a GUI system to map input to the single pixel ?

Comment: Are the labels unique? Meaning if you have a label, there is no duplicate one?

Comment: shouldn't you create a point class, create its object with x and y values and push them in stack?

Comment: @amar that is part of the design of the internal OO programming, I'm not interested about that, I'm simply interested about how to map input to a window or a widget. Just the data structure to use.

Comment: @AliAlamiri the problem is a little bit more complicated than that, for example when rescaling you have to re-adjust the layout, and no, I don't think that I need an associative container for that, it's expensive and doesn't really fit.

Comment: Unless you have a few billion pixels, who cares if resizing is 'expensive' (linear in the number of pixels)? By any reasonable assumption, you're not going to be resizing all the time.

Comment: @Dukeling yes and no, for example modern ARM devices have relatively high density display when at the same time they have a relatively low bandwidth between memory and CPU, also the CPU is often times not really up to the task of computing such things so quickly. Also there are quite a few low power devices with billions of pixels already on the market, so I need something that scales.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you want is a [quadtree](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree).

Comment: thanks, I will take a look at that, in the meantime I'm open to other solutions. Any words on how this problem is solve in other GUI frameworks ?

Comment: better its still  if you paste some text if in case link becomes in active for some reason

Comment: Using a quadtree is the best method of which I am aware. You may be able to find situation-specific shortcuts that prune the tree prior to searching in a real application, but log n would still be the best asymptotic complexity. I would recommend looking at Android's source, but I almost guarantee that's how it's done.

Comment: @user2485710 Not long after I posted the previous comment, I knew I shouldn't have written what I did. That's what I get writing answers from the train. Anyway, Android takes a much more naive approach to dispatching motion events, simply traversing the view hierarchy and checking if a point is contained in the control's frame. I suppose they have reasoned it's better to keep things simple until that is no longer good enough.

Comment: can you name the classes/files involved in this ?

Comment: [ViewGroup.java](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/view/ViewGroup.java), `dispatchTouchEvent` method starting on line 1834.

Comment: thanks, I appreciate that but I'm still in the same situation as before posting this question on SO ...

Comment: Not exactly the same position. I haven't seen an example GUI framework that uses a quadtree, but I haven't looked much. And I have seen a few forum posts that seem to indicate a quadtree is just the way to do it. Or structure your elements in a regular tree like Android and give each a chance to handle events. Either way resolves your scalability concerns, and it would take considerably complex UI before performance is a problem (although quadtree resolves that too).